# AWS Lambda - time.time() returns undefined

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Im working with a lambda function where i use boto3 to put_item() into my DynamoBD Table and on the code im adding the ttl parameter (Time to live).

```
ttl = str(int(time.time() + 2629746))
```

This line gives me a 1 month ttl but for some reason im getting alot of this errors:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: undefined: ClientError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 52, in handler
response = c_put_item(d)
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 40, in c_put_item
'ttl':{'N':ttl}
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 317, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 615, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: undefined
```

Any idea why?

PS: im using python3

-- EDIT:

Im adding a little bit more of the code.
For some reason this isnt working.

```
    ttl = str(int(time.time() + 2629746))

    response = client.put_item(TableName='MYTABLENAME',Item={
        'item':{'S':item},
        'title':{'S':title},
        'link':{'S':link},
        'price':{'N':price},
        'category':{'S':category},
        'avaliable':{'S':avaliable},
        'image':{'S':image},
        'ttl':{'N':ttl}
    })
```

-- EDIT2:

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html) specify you should use the put_item() as i did except im forced to use str() cause i was getting an error.

Comment: Can you post a longer snippet of your code? Maybe the `handler` function where the exception is getting triggered.

Comment: Is `ttl` the only field you're updating? That message doesn't necessarily say `ttl` is `None`. It says one of the fields of the entire call is `None`.

Comment: In the console of DynamoDB try to manually add an item. What is the type of `ttl` column ? If you have already added some values in the column, it takes the type the first put. Does it work with `'ttl':{'S':'123'}` ?

Comment: All the values have to be passed as strings.Can you add more details as to what values are you passing...as in what is the value of `price` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kichik was actually right on his comment. This error doesn't necessarily say ttl is `None`. It says one of the fields of the entire call is `None`.

So ones i detected the conflicting field i added an exception and the problem stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making `ttl` an integer: `ttl = int(time.time() + 2629746)`

[Boto3 docs, Creating a new item](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#creating-a-new-item):

> For all of the valid types that can be used for an item, refer to [Valid DynamoDB Types](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#ref-valid-dynamodb-types):
>
> These are the valid item types to use with Boto3 Table Resource (dynamodb.Table) and DynamoDB:
> • integer – Number (N)
> • decimal.Decimal – Number (N)

Comment: Try it. From [Boto3 docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item): `table.put_item(
    Item={
        'string': 'string'|123|Binary(b'bytes')|True|None|set(['string'])|set([123])|set([Binary(b'bytes')])|[]|{}
    }, ........`. It may and must be a number.

Comment: That gets me this error: Invalid type for parameter Item.ttl.N, value: 1523493632, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Comment: Do you get the error with `ttl = str(int(time.time() + 2629746))` or with `ttl = int(time.time() + 2629746)` ?

Comment: One of these must pass : `'ttl':{'S':'123'}`, `'ttl':{'N':456}`. Which one? Also try to put a new column: `numberTTL: {'N': int(time.time() + 2629746)}`. Does it work?